# Why my succes-msg or error-msg are not display?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

well, in my js files, i'm trying to display success-ms or error-msg. I don't understang why my div #error-msg or #success-msg doesn't appear.

Here my js code. If user clicks on confirm, data are sent to process.php to insert the keyword in my mysql table

```
     $(function()

{
  $('#alert-change').click(function(event){

  $("#error-msg12").html('');
  $("#success-msg12").html('');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('include/process.php',$('#alert-change-form').serialize(),function(resp)
    {
      if (resp['status'] == true)
      {
        $("#success-msg12").html(resp['msg']+"");
        $("#success-msg12").show();
      }
      else
      {
        var htm = '<button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>';
        $.each(resp['msg'],function(index,val){
          htm += val+" <br>";
          });
        $("#error-msg12").html(htm);
        $("#error-msg12").show(); 
      }
    },'json');
  });

});
```

My form

```
<div id="myModal_alert" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-login1">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form name="alert-change-form"  id="alert-change-form" method="post">
        <div class="modal-header">        
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add a keyword.</h4>
         <div class="alert" id="error-msg12">
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-msg12">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">   
         <input type="hidden" id="process" name="process" value="4">   
          <input type="hidden" id="first_name" value ="<?= $_SESSION['name']?>" class="form-control" name="first_name" minlength="3" maxlength="10" placeholder="" class="login"   />       
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <label>add a keywordt.</label>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="kw" class="form-control" name="alert"  placeholder="" class="kw" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" id="alert-change">Confirmer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my process.php file

```
if ($_POST['process'] == '4') { 

    $error  = array();
    $res    = array();
    $success = "";
    $alert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alert']);
    echo $_POST['first_name'];
    echo $alert;
    // errors
    if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9_]+$#", $alert))
        {
            $error[] = 'error 1';
        }

    if (strlen($alert) < 2)
        {
        $error[] = 'error 2';
        }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_alert WHERE user = :user AND kw = :alert";
    $req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindParam(':user', $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $req->bindParam(':alert', $alert, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req->execute();
    $resultat = $req->fetchAll();
    if (count($resultat))
        {
            $error[] = 'error 3';
        }

    if(count($error)>0)
        {
            $resp['msg']    = $error;
            $resp['status'] = false;    
            echo json_encode($resp);
            exit;
        } 

    // on exécute
        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users_alert (user,kw) VALUES (:user,:kw)";        
        $run = $bdd->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $run->bindParam(':user', $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $run->bindParam(':kw', $alert, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $run->execute();    
        $resp['msg']    = "success1";
        $resp['status'] = true; 
        echo json_encode($resp);
        exit;   
        }
```

I've tried 4/5 things, in vain.
Somebody has an idea ?

Comment: Well for one, stop using `mysql_*` functions. If your PHP is up to date, as it should, it won't even work anymore.

Comment: few things I found in your code, stop using [mysql_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php ) these are deprecated.  remove unnecessary *echo * from your process.php.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete them in the **process.php** file and try again?

```
echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo $alert;
```

If this is not working, you should capture the post values ​​you sent to the **process.php** file and go step by step.